# How to i change the time stamp using php mysql

Tags: php

My friend using phpfox social network. He intergrating the phpfox with his own application.
In phpfox site they are using the time stamp like this  `1297503935` (DB data type : int(10) ).We wre not able to find what way ther are using to get num as a time stamp . Is there is any way to change this integer into normal time stamp.

Comment: That looks like a normal time stamp to me. What result are you expecting?

Comment: so what does echo date('d-M-Y H:i:s',1297503935); give you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation for [php date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$timestamp=1297503935;
date ( DATE_RFC822 ,  $timestamp );
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI: A "normal timestamp" is an integer. It's [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

PHP's sense of time is based on this integer and there are [plenty of functions](http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/ref.datetime.php) to deal with it.